# Angular: onclick method is being called when changing text on text field

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Anuglar JS Just learning the basics and i wrote the following program:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/mycontroller.js"></script>
    </head>
<body ng-app="myapp">

    <div ng-controller="MyFirstController">

        <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username">
        <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="checkvalidate()">
        Username entered is {{username}}
        Result is {{checkvalidate()}}
    </div>
```

and my controller is

```
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('MyFirstController',function($scope)
              {

    $scope.checkvalidate=function()
    {
      //  alert($scope.username);
        console.log("called");
        var user=$scope.username;
        if(user.indexOf('@')!=-1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };
});
```

As i enter text in the textfield the method checkvalidate() is called for every character entered. Why is this being called.

Kindly update thing i am missing to understand here.
thanks

Comment: small suggestion: no need to create your title in all caps

Comment: due apologies. just inadvertently typed in caps

Answer (score 3):

You outputting:

```
Result is {{checkvalidate()}}
```

When view is refreshed it's asking your function for data. And View is refreshed every time you change your username model.
Assign your validation to variable and output that on view.
Something like:

```
$scope.isValid = false;
$scope.checkvalidate=function()
    {
      //  alert($scope.username);
        console.log("called");
        var user=$scope.username;
        if(user.indexOf('@')!=-1)
            $scope.isValid = true;
        else
            $scope.isValid = false;
    };
```

And than in html:

```
Username entered is {{username}}
Result is {{isValid }}
```

Comment: Haha we submitted our answers at the same time :)

Comment: thanks it was helpful.this means that the entire view is refreshed when even one model value is changed.

Comment: will this mean that adding a code like            <div ng-init="count=1"></div>
    value is {{increment()}}
            
    </div>   to the code where increment() method changes count will lead to an infinite loop.kindly update

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Angular's digest cycle when you print the method in the line:

```
Result is {{checkvalidate()}}
```

I'd recommend in the checkValidate function setting a "isValid" variable to keep track of whether it is valid or not. That way you can print it without this happening.

```
Result is {{isValid}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular, like a bunch of other modern frontend view frameworks implements [data binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binding).

This means Angular let's you write views in a **declarative syntax**. For example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <input ng-model="username" type="text"/>
  <p>The username is {{username}}
</div>
```

This means, "let this input handle the variable `username`". It doesn't neccessarily mean that angular will watch the `onchange` event, as the `ng-model` directive can be used on a bunch of different types of inputs, even non HTML5 standard ones.

Each time angular redraws the view it will ask for the value of username to the scope and change the view.

Something similar happens when you interpolate the call to á function like `checkvalidate`.